# How to navigate to another page in android?

Tags: android

I'm new to android. Please tell me how to navigate to a new page in android.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:How to start a new activity from an existing activity

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In android to navigate to another page means you have to start another activity. for starting a new activity use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity.this, nextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

You should mention the next activity in the AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 0):

To change your page (i think you're refering to "Activities" in android you need to issue a so called "intent").

You cann do that by:

```
startActivity(new Intent(nextactivity,NextActivity.class));
```

or

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(nextactivity,NextActivity.class),1);
```

if you want the new Activity to return any result to the activity who started the new one.

But what i recommend is, that you read this documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

and come back to this question if you have need additional assistance on concrete problems on that topics.

i hope that helps.