# Multi-page application with corresponding pictures and text

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, image

I'm new to Java and Android. I have been trying for the past week to make an app for my phone. The app consists of 4 pages, which are diagrammed below:

[image: Diagram explaining four pages]

- Page 1: Contains a picture taking up the size of the screen. If I click on the picture it needs to go to "page 2".
- Page 2: Consists of an icon on the left (say the flag for instance) followed by a text field (eg. USA). When "USA" strip is clicked it needs to go to page 3.
- Page 3: Consists of text, picture and then more text from a string. This page needs to correspond to the strip clicked on in page 2 ("USA" in this example). There are also two buttons at the bottom of "page 3" and "page 4" which when pressed need to go to the corresponding page numbers.
- Page 4: This page is displayed if the "More" button is pressed on "page 3".

I would like this phone to work on a minimum Android 2.2 or 2.3. All logos, pictures and string texts need to be locally available (resources folder) and not website based. I have tried all sorts of combinations of `ListView`'s and buttons with `OnClickListener`'s as well as toast screens. My limited knowledge of programming is frustrating.

My question is if there is a template around which will help me out with this app? Or if there are any web resources.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, individual "pages" or "screens" can be implemented as `Activity`s. You need to extend the `Activity` class and add the components that you wish to display. Most of the layout can be done in an XML file. I strongly suggest that you google for a tutorial that illustrates the basics of Android programming. From there, you can start by creating an app with two pages. And then just keep adding a little bit at a time until you get the complete app that you want.

Answer (score 0):

There some easy ways to do this. If you want to be backwards compatible to SDK 8 you can do this in two ways. You can use Fragments or Activities for each layout. If you implement fragments, I suggest reading http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html inside there you will about using the FragmentActivity instead of the Activity. Read this link http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html as it will have the needed libraries to implement the Fragments in older versions of the SDK. It does looks like you looking for some navigation buttons that reside on the bottom of the layout. In order to fully implement a layout that has this view on the bottom of the screen in SDK 8, you will need to create your own View and place it on the bottom of the screen. RelativeLayout and alignParentBottom = "true" will accomplish this. There is also a way to do this using a ViewPager which will also work in the backwards compatibility requirements you have. I am sorry the amount of information I am throwing at you but I really would recommend looking into other questions posted by users on this topic. [How to navigate to another page in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202800/how-to-navigate-to-another-page-in-android) for example. Good luck and everything you are looking for is able to be learned through a Google search. Maybe not all at once.