# Navigate from page A to page B with a button

Tags: android, button, navigation

How can I go from page A to Page B with a simple Button ?

XML Code is the following

```
<Button
    android:text="Page Suivante"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="137dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnPSuiv"
    android:onClick="pageSuivante"/>
```

and code in MainActivity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    /** send the user to the second form **/
    public void goToContact(View view){
        Intent intent new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

    }

}
```

I know I have to create an Intent Object but I dont fully understand how to procede.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to navigate to another page in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202800/how-to-navigate-to-another-page-in-android)

Comment: Go check some tutorials on internet, I always suggest "thenewboston" on youtube or on their site, they have a really good tutorial from newbie to basic

Comment: Thanks guys ! I managed to do it. I'll check those tutorials also.

Answer (score 1):

Button has a method setOnClickListener which also have a [great example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) in the Button widget deference page, which will tell exactly what you want.

Simply fetch the button from the activity using findViewById method with the id of button given as parameter

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
```

after that you can setOnClickListener simply by passing the listener performing the action as a parameter, usually as a anonymous class

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
        }
});
```

After that you only need to perform moving from view a to view b, which is usually performed using Activitys, therefore Intent is used to start the new Activity

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need start the `intent` to navigate

```
 /** send the user to the second form **/
    public void goToContact(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the onClick attribute in XML:

```
<Button
    android:text="Page Suivante"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="137dp"
    android:id="@+id/btnPSuiv"
    android:onClick="goToContact"/>
```

change the **goToContact()** to:

```
public void goToContact(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```